# Basic understanding of react-nativgation theming on class based components

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation, android-dark-theme

I'm still a newbie with react-native coding, but almost completed my project by now.
one of my last steps is to use theming for android on that project.
since the current docs of react navigation (5?) are just function based i am having a really hard time to understand this functionality.
so i set up a sample project to learn and hopefully understand this.
here we go:
App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import home from './home';
import screen2 from './Screen2';

import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme, DarkTheme  } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
const scheme = useColorScheme();

const MyDarkTheme = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    primary: "#9933FF",
    background: "#000000",
    card: "#000000",
    text: "#ffffff",
    border: "#000028",
    notification: "#9933FF",
    green: "#00ff00"
  }
}

  return (
    <>
    <AppearanceProvider>
        <NavigationContainer theme={scheme === "dark" ? MyDarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
            <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={home}  />
                <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={screen2}  />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </AppearanceProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

home.js

```
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function Home() {
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{color: colors.text}}>this is the Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
        title="Go To Screen 2"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("screen2")}
        />
    </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Screen2.js

```
 import { ThemeContext , ThemeColors, useTheme, useNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
 import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

 class Screen2 extends Component {

  static contextType = ThemeContext;

  render() {
    const { colors } = this.context
   return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
         <View style={{backgroundColor: 'gray', padding: 10}}>
            <Text style={{color: this.context.colors.text}}>this is screen 2</Text> 
         </View>
     </View>
   );
  }
 };
 
 export default Screen2;
```

i just can't get that colors.text working in screen2.js
same with navigation.navigate

i thought maybe i have to use navigation from 'react-navigation', which i think should be react-navi v4 in class based projects, and '@react-navigation/native' (v5?) in function based components, but i just can't get it..
by now i am feeling kind of lost, this is driving me crazy!
i am even thinking about converting my whole project to function based instead of class based, but this would be a lot of work, i mean really a lot!
and i have to use my own color-sets as well, not just the standard colors provided by react-native themes...
so where to go from here? :/

Comment: Why are you using this.context.colors.text if you already destructured the this.context object.  You can now use colors.text

Comment: that's one of many things i already tried..if i do so i get; "Component Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'colors.text')

Comment: hm..i guess i will have to convert all my classes to functions..thanks anyway ;)